# Put method return unauthorized

Tags: angular, jwt

I'm new in Angular and I have a service like this:

```
readonly rootUrl = "http://myapi.net/";

  private serviceUrl = "http://myapi.net/api/usuarios/listar";
  headers = new Headers({
    Authorization:
      "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
  options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
```

so there I get user auntentication, then I create method like:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}
postSwitch() {
    var cambioEstatus = this.http
      .put(this.rootUrl + "api/usuarios/activar", this.options)
      .map((data: any) => data.json());
    return cambioEstatus;
  }
```

And finally use in component like:

```
onFlagChange(event) {
    this.UsuariosService.postSwitch().subscribe(
      () => {
        //React to your HTTP request success
        this.toastr.success("Success");
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error("Fail");
        //React to your HTTP request error
      }
    );
  }
```

But it always return error 401 unauthorized, extrange thing is if I execute it with postman it don't returns that error. And another methods(get) like:

```
listarEmpresas() {
    var empresas = this.http
      .get(this.rootUrl + "api/empresas/listar", this.options)
      .map((data: any) => data.json());
    console.log(empresas);
    return empresas;
  }
```

Don't throw this error, there is another thing I need to do for `put` actions? Regards

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqwhD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CORS issue and you need to enable CORS on your server or try 
 to add below to your header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Also, try to pass body with your request.

```
postSwitch() {
var cambioEstatus = this.http
  .put(this.rootUrl + "api/usuarios/activar", body, this.options)
  .map((data: any) => data.json());
return cambioEstatus;
```

}

For enabling CORS for testing use the below chrome flag

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue... I think the problem is that put requires a request body but get doesn't, thus between the url and the options, you need a body, like `.get(this.rootUrl + "api/empresas/listar", {}, this.options)`